# c# controlling program flow l by object type while in a loop

Tags: c#

I am working with a system which allows users to add C.V.s to a company database. A document consists of sections and for each section there can be one or more fields. A field corresponds to a user control which is mapped to a specific field type. The user controls are not bound to the document object in any way and to save data to the document from the page containing the user controls there is a method like this:

```
public void SaveData(Document document)
{
    // Get all user controls on the page
    var userControls = FindDescendants<UserControl>(this);

    foreach (var section in document.Sections)
    {
        foreach (var field in section.Fields)
        {
            if (field is Address)
            {
                var address = field as Address;

                var addressControl = userControls.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ClientID.Contains(field.Id)) as AddressUserControl;
                addressControl.SaveData(address);
            }
            else if (field is TelephoneNumbers)
            {
                var telephoneNumbers = field as TelephoneNumbers;

                var telephoneNumbersControl = userControls.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ClientID.Contains(field.Id)) as TelephoneNumbersUserControl;
                telephoneNumbersControl.SaveData(telephoneNumbers);
            }
            ...
            ...
            else if (field is Employment)
            {
                var employment = field as Employment;

                var employmentControl = userControls.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ClientID.Contains(field.Id)) as EmploymentUserControl;
                employmentControl.SaveData(employment);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I do not like the nested loops and each time a new field type is added the conditional statement within the foreach grows.

Any ideas how this could be structured more elegantly?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: anyway, can't you just put `userControls.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ClientID.Contains(field.Id)).SaveData(field);` and remove all of the ifs?

Comment: hi loli, thanks for you help. Unfortunately no as the SaveData method takes a different type of parameter for each type of control

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the code for UserControl and the Field classes?